# Stopping a user getting to the second page of a form

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a form that a user has to completely fill out before they are able to register for a website. What i'm trying to counter is if the user gets to url of the second page by accident. I've tried using if(!isPostBack) and then inside the if statement redirecting them to the first page but that only works the first time, and the user can never hit the second page that displays their details when they click on the submit button because the second page is now a post back. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this. You could use `Session` to store user progress. Also, if you have a long multi-page form you could have a master table for your form in the database that tracks user progress (column named `ProgressPage`, for example).

Comment: +1 Session is really the way to do this. Even something as simple as setting `Session["IsCompleted"] = true; Response.Redirect("/Page2");` And on Page2 `if (!(bool)Session["IsCompleted"]) Response.Redirect("/Page1");`